# MVC4 duplicated UserProfile table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project I use MVC4 and some external database using Entity as orm.

I decided to use membership given by MVC, so I just changed in default `ConnectionString` to point to my external db.

Then, when I launch the app first time, few tables were added, so far so good. Now, the **problem is** , that when I map new created userProfile table into my dataContext model, then I have a conflict, because this table allready exists in accountModel.

Account model and my new generated model are in the same namespace, which I don't wanna change, so what can I do?

here is class generate by ADO entity model using view add tables method:

```
public partial class UserProfile
    {
        public UserProfile()
        {
            this.Predictions = new HashSet<Prediction>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Prediction> Predictions { get; set; }
    }
```

and here from membership

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
    public partial class UserProfile
        {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        }
```

both exist in the same name space, and are in conflict.

Comment: Can you supply more info? what is the connection string written in the method either in global.asax or under filter folder in class called "InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute" which looks like this WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(DEFAULTCONNECTION, "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

Comment: I don't get u exactly, I found this method which u've mentioned WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true); and then DefaultConnection in my webconfig looks like this: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="PersistSecurityInfo=True;User ID=**;Password=**;Data Source=**;Initial Catalog=myDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: The problem is that this membership has already definition for userProfile class, but lets say i have in my main model another table in relations with userProfil, so I map both: this table and userProfile table, and then we have a problem, first visual says , this class has allrady definition so make it partial, but i don't wanna change model manually, but even if i change to partial , then we have redundands fields and so on....

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework Code First? can you add the dataContext to your question?

Comment: no i am not using code first, I said word "map table" i use desinger

Comment: I have the same problem,if U have found solution,give me some directions,please.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the auto generated class and create a partial class to extend the AccountModel UserProfile class instead.

Create a partial class with the same name and same namespace:

```
public partial class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.Predictions = new HashSet<Prediction>();
    }        

    public virtual ICollection<Prediction> Predictions { get; set; }
}
```

By doing this, you have the `Predictions` property into the membership `UserProfile` class.