# associating my own table to userProfile table in SqlMembership doesn't work as expected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sqlmembershipprovider

I have this table named `Person` :
FirstName,LastName,BirthDate,UserId(FK,int,not null)

`userId` field is joint to userProfile table of SqlMembership

and 2 other tables named `Category` and `News` besides SqlMembership tables like `UserInRole,...` in a database

I create a .edmx file and add my own tables (Category,News,Person) to it.cause my approach is database first.

now I except when I get current logged in user,I can access it's related `person`:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var context = new UsersContext();
            var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == "asma");
            ViewBag.fullName= user.person.FirstName+' '+user.person.LastName; //ERROR
        }
```

but when I write `user.` the intellisense just gives me 2 fields:UserId and UserName

where is `user.person....`

on the other hand I cannot add `UserProfile` to my .edmx file.adding `UserProfile` to .edmx file causes ['MVC4 duplicated UserProfile table' problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170339/mvc4-duplicated-userprofile-table)

What's my fault?adding my own tables to the database that is created by SqlMembership?